# Календарь jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
if(dateText=="01/01/2012")
style.backgroundImage='url(C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\jQuery\ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png)';
});
</script>
```

скажите пожалуйста, у меня здесь есть ошибки? вроде всё правильно, а всё равно не работает... консоли не нравится скобка после if...

Comment: странный код, datepicker() это функция, внутрь которой передается массив с параметрами {par1:true, par2: 'fade'}, а у вас вместо массива if

Comment: @makregistr, я что-то не понял, как мне сделать, чтобы работало?  если что это jquery

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте документцию [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect), там есть описание callback функций, вам нужна функция onSelect, которая срабатывает после выбора даты и именно в ней сделать вашу проверку

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ if(dateText=="01/01/2012") {
$(находим элемент для смены стиля).css('background','url(../bg.png) no-repeat');
} }
});
```

Comment: мне не нужен onSelect, мне нужно чтобы сразу фон поменялся

Comment: ну у вас и запросы! фон чего? покажите разметку хотя бы!

Comment: Когда вы задавали этот же вопрос в прошлый раз вам посоветовали прочитать про jquery и про ui datepicker, советом вы не воспользовались и просто продублировали вопрос. Код не верный, поскольку внутрь функции надо передавать параметры, а не очередную функцию, поэтому консоль и ругается на лишние знаки и прочее - их там просто не должно быть в том виде, в котором они сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Скобки действительно нет. Хотя это не критично, но попробуйте так. и откуда берется dateText?

```
   if(dateText=="01/01/2012") {
        style.backgroundImage='url(C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\jQuery\ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png)';
    }
```

Comment: скобки {} не нужны там. переделал не много, сделал так:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    function(dateText, inst) {
    if(dateText=="01/01/2012")
    style.backgroundImage='url(C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\jQuery\ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png)';
    });
    });
    </script>
всё равно не работает. ему не нравится "(" (после if)

Comment: нет, теперь не нравится function

Comment: в datapicker обычно передаются параметры для датапикера, а не собственные функции. Вам придется либо влезать в код самого датапикера либо попытаться как то расширить плагин другими средствами. Такой вариант как вы написали не пройдет